# how to set images on AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-button

I want to set the background image in `AlertDialog`, here is my code:

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)


               .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       MainActivity.this.finish();
                   }
               })

               .setNeutralButton("Rate Us", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
               .setNegativeButton("No", null)
               .show();
```

In this code I want to set images on button separately, on message separately, on title separately and background image separately anyone please help me how can I do it?

Comment: I think create popup like alertdialog

Comment: lot of answers has been given on this .. try to google first !!

Answer (score 1):

In such a case you should create your own `View` for this dialog by calling [setView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29). You can take a look on a small tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/), or [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout). You can definitely customize title and body of `AlertDialog`, but not buttons, afaik. If you are willing to customize dialog's buttons, you should create you own `CustomDialog` class by extending base `Dialog` class:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog
```

And you'll be able to make all the customizations you need there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.title)
    .setTitle("Quit")
    .setMessage("Are you sure want to quit CERTIFICATION HUB?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   MainActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })

           .setNeutralButton("Rate Us", new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
    .show();
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: So its solving of of the issue of user3409263

Comment: He still search for other issue but i'm helping in any isn't that good??

Comment: it's not solving the issue, this code doesn't set custom background to title, body and buttons

Comment: It's setting image on title and that's also an requirement.